# How can I solve the following linear program?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to find the answer for the following linear program.

Max $v$

subject to
$$v-5x_1-x_2 \le 0 $$
$$ v-x_1-4x_2 \le 0 $$
$$ v-2x_1-3x_2 \le 0 $$
$$ x_1+x_2 = 1 $$
$$ x_1, x_2 \ge 0  $$
$$ v \in R $$

I know how to solve following linear program by using MATLAB
$$C^T x$$
$$s.t. Ax \le b  $$
$$x \ge 0$$

We can solve this by the following MATLAB code

```
[x, fval]=linprog(C, A, b)
```

How can I solve the above linear program by using MATLAB?
I cannot identify C, A, b matrices and their dimentions in the above problem.

The answers should be 
$$x_1=0.4, x_2=0.6, v=2.6$$

---

My second problem is

$$ 3x_1-7x_2 \le y$$
$$ -3x_2-5x_3 \le y$$
$$ -x_1-7x_2 \le y$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3 =1 $$ 
$$x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0 $$

Comment: If you are imposing the constraints $x_1+x_2 = 0$ and $x_1,x_2 \ge 0$, then that forces $x_1 = x_2 = 0$. Then all of the other inequalities become $v \le 0$, so the maximum of $v$ subject to all of those constraints is simply $0$. Are you sure you wrote down the constraints correctly?

Comment: First, let $x_3=v$, and then notice that linprogs syntax is more general with many more inputs as it allows for equality constraints and general lower and upper variable bounds.

Comment: Sorry! I have edited my question. $x_1+x_2=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality constraint can be passed on in the Aeq,beq parameters. I.e.

```
>> f=[-1,0,0]; A=[1,-5,-1;1,-1,-4;1,-2,-3]; b=[0;0;0]; A2=[0,1,1]; b2=1; lo=[-inf,0,0]; up=[inf,inf,inf];
>> [x,fval]=linprog(f,A,b,A2,b2,lo,up);
Optimization terminated.
>> x

x =

    2.6000
    0.4000
    0.6000

>> fval

fval =

   -2.6000
```

Comment: According to your MATLAB code, fval=6.0822e-12.  But, since I want to maximize v (v=2.6), the value of the objective function(fval) and the value of v should have the same value, right? I'm little bit confused. Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: No you should get fval =  -2.6000

Comment: I'm sorry. It gives the right answer. But I have another matlab code. It  doesn't  give the right answer. It is similar to the above. It gives a wrong value for fval. Could you please help me with this? Here is the code.  >>f=[1;0;0;0]; A=[-1,0,3,-7;-1,-3,0,5;-1,7,-5,0]; b=[0;0;0]; A2=[0,1,1,1]; b2=1; lo=[-inf,0,0,0]; up=[inf,inf,inf,inf];
>>[x,fval]=linprog(f,A,b,A2,b2,lo,up)

Comment: You must have made a mistake.

Comment: I tried to find the mistake. But I couldn't

Comment: Could you please help me to find the mistake?

Comment: We need to know what you are trying to model. As it stands now there is not enough information to find out what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry! Those answers are similar. There is no mistake

Answer (score 0):

Second answer for extra bonus points.

First note that you first equation looks very suspicious: $−u+3x_2−7x_2≤0$ and does not correspond to the first row in $A$.

Second `1e-12` vs `0` is very close. Within the tolerances. I would be happy with such a result. If you really care about this minuscule differences, solve with dual simplex method:

```
>> options = optimoptions(@linprog,'Algorithm','dual-simplex');
>> [x, fval]=linprog(f, A, b, A2, b2, lo, up, [], options)

Optimal solution found.


x =

         0
    0.3333
    0.4667
    0.2000


fval =

     0
```

The second question has been removed by the poster so this answer is now a bit hanging in the air. Not sure what is happening with these bonus points.

Comment: Deleting questions after they have been answered is not very nice.

Comment: I'm sorry! I deleted that question because it is not a good question. You have answered it correctly. Since you have answered my all questions very nicely, I will add that question again.

Comment: Thank you very much once again for clear explanations.